# Looping inside render renders twice

Tags: react-native

I need to loop inside my render but if I return inside it it renders twice. Is there are way to loop inside my return but only render once?

```
return (
  <OverviewWrapper>

      {stylesArray.map(function(object, i){
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight key={i} onPress={openQuestionOverview} style={[styles.punt, stylesArray[i]]}>
                <Image source={vragen[i]} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
      })}
  </OverviewWrapper>
)
```

Comment: Just use ListView. I can't imagine a case why would anyone do loop in render.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code you have posted. I think the issue is somewhere else, you are modifying the state of that component in some component lifecycle method call or parent component updated the props of child view.